# Spinner adapter isnt working

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have created a custom adapter class for spinner, which can take object type values. But weirdly its showing some error in code.

**SpinAdapter class**

```
public class SpinAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country> 
 {
    private Context context;
    private Country[] values;

    public SpinAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, Country[] values) 
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    public int getCount(){
       return values.length;
    }

    public Country getItem(int position){
       return values[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position){
       return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView label = new TextView(context);
        label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        label.setText(values[position].getName());
        return label;
    }
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView label = new TextView(context);
        label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        label.setText(values[position].getName());

        return label;
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class CityActivity extends Activity {

EditText cityNameTxtBox;
EditText cityAboutTxtBox;
EditText cityPopulationTxtBox;

private Spinner mySpinner;
    private SpinAdapter adapter;
     ArrayList<Country> countries;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_city);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

    Country aCountry = new Country("a","1");
    Country bCountry = new Country("b","2");
    Country cCountry = new Country("c","3");
    countries.add(aCountry);
    countries.add(bCountry);
    countries.add(cCountry);

    adapter = new SpinAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countries);

    mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.countrySpinner);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

The problem is showing when i am trying to make a instance of new SpinAdapter inside onCreate().

```
adapter = new SpinAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countries);
```

Its showing error for *this* keyword. how am i going to fix it? what should be the COntext to pass if its not *this*?

Comment: `this` should be fine. what is the error?

Comment: The constructor SpinAdapter(CityActivity, int, ArrayList<Country>) is undefined

Comment: Apporv answered your question. `this` has nothing to do with your error

Answer (score 5):

You are passing an `ArrayList<Country>` in your `SpinnerAdapter` constructor but you need to pass a `Country[]`.

This is the reason it is giving you an error.

Either change your constructor or pass `Country[]` instead of `ArrayList<Country>`

Comment: ya..Thanks.. I realized that later.  :-)